# `grub2-mkconfig`: skip a particular device for locating kernel

Tags: fedora, kernel, lvm, grub

I updated grub as follows:

```bash
$ sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
Generating grub configuration file ...
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[240340]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 45665: grub2-probe
File descriptor 9 (pipe:[208755]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 45665: grub2-probe
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[240340]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 45665: grub2-probe
File descriptor 9 (pipe:[208755]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 45665: grub2-probe
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[240340]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 45718: grub2-probe
File descriptor 9 (pipe:[208755]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 45718: grub2-probe
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[240340]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 45718: grub2-probe
File descriptor 9 (pipe:[208755]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 45718: grub2-probe
Found Ubuntu 22.10 (22.10) on /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-Data
Found Ubuntu 23.04 (23.04) on /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-UbuntuRoot
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

- It found `Ubuntu 22.10 (22.10) on /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-Data`, how can I instruct to avoid looking for kernels and operating system in a particular device `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-Data`?